# Air date picker disable dates styling not effect in current month

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm currently using air date picker (latest version). When I'm trying to enable some random dates using onRenderCell function, other dates are disabling with proper styling (like date displaying with light ash color etc.) but in current month, styling is not effect to some dates.

Here is my code.

```
<div id="disabled-days" class="datepicker-style-01" data-datepicker="true" 
data-range="true" data-multiple-dates-separator=" - " data-picker-option='{"inline":true,"language":"my-lang"}' 
data-future-only="true"></div>

<script>
   var enabledDays = ['2021-10-24','2021-10-27','2021-10-30','2021-11-25','2021-11-28'];

   $('#disabled-days').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
        onRenderCell: function onRenderCell(date, cellType) {
           if (cellType == 'day') {
              var day = (date.getFullYear()+'-'+(('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2))+'-'+(('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)));
              var isDisabled = enabledDays.indexOf(day) == -1;
              return {
                 disabled: isDisabled
              }
           }
        }
   })
</script>
```

Below are the images of current month and next month results. (Enabled Dates are marked in Red Color). (29th and 31st of Current Month/October is disabled, but above mentioned styles are not properly set.)

[image: Current Month]

[image: Next Month]

I can't figure out the exact reason of this problem. Can someone help me to figure this out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine to me!

```js
$(function(){
   var enabledDays = ['2021-10-24','2021-10-27','2021-10-30','2021-11-25','2021-11-28'];

   $('#disabled-days').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
        onRenderCell: function onRenderCell(date, cellType) {
           if (cellType == 'day') {
              var day = (date.getFullYear()+'-'+(('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2))+'-'+(('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)));
              var isDisabled = enabledDays.indexOf(day) == -1;
              return {
                 disabled: isDisabled
              }
           }
        }
   })
});
```

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="disabled-days" class="datepicker-style-01" data-datepicker="true" 
data-range="true" data-multiple-dates-separator=" - " data-picker-option='{"inline":true,"language":"my-lang"}' 
data-future-only="true"></div>
```